# Nokogiri extract data from xml

Tags: xml, ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri

i try to extract data from a xml in rails application with the Nokogiri gem,

**the xml** :

```
<item>
    <description>
        <![CDATA[<img src="something" title="anothething">
        <p>text, bla bla...</p>]]>
    </description>
</item>
```

Actually i do something like this to extract data from the xml :

```
def test_content
    @return = Array.new
    site = 'http://www.les-encens.com/modules/feeder/rss.php?id_category=0'
    @doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(site, "UserAgent" => "Ruby-OpenURI"))
    @doc.xpath("//item").each do |n|
        @return << [
            n.xpath('description')
        ] 
   end
end
```

Could you show me how extract just the **src** attribute from the **img** tag ?

**Edit :**
I have replace the xml by the correct one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result of an xpath call made in Nokogiri is going to be a [NodeSet](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html), which is simply a list of Nokigiri [Nodes](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html)

With this in mind we can just pull examples from the Nokogiri Documentation and adapt them.

To answer your question, **"Could you show me how extract just the src attribute from the img tag ?"**, here is one such way.

```
#the 'open' method here is part of the open-uri library
xml = Nokogiri::XML(open(your_url_here))

all_images = xml.xpath("//img") #returns NodeSet (list of Nokogiri Nodes)

image_sources = []

#iterate through each node
all_images.each() do |node|
  image_sources << node.get_attribute('src') #One method
  #image_sources << node['src'] #Another convention we could use
end
```

As Phrogz notes below, a more idomatic way of pulling the 'src' attribute from all of the images nodes is to map the 'src' attribute directly rather than iterating and pushing onto an array.

```
image_sources = all_images.map{ |node| node['src'] }
```

Comment: May I suggest `image_sources = all_images.map{ |node| node['src'] }` as better and more idiomatic than creating an array and pushing into it?

Comment: For sure. I tried to make the code as clear as possible. For someone not 100% clear on map, it might be a bit confusing. But I agree the idiomatic way should be presented.

Comment: A little detail the content is a XML page and the <img> are in CDATA and when i try this code i didn't get the img src. @Phrogz thank for the map method example ^^

Comment: I tried to use "Nokogiri::XML::ParseOptions.NOCDATA" but it's return a NoMethodError

Comment: Awea - Can you provide a sample snippet (e.g. gist), or a link to the document you are trying to parse?

Comment: It's ok, i have solved my problem. Thank a lot :) i've mix XML and HTML parser to get the result what i want

Answer (score 1):

My solution code, thank to @Douglas and @Phrogz

```
def test_content
    site = 'xml-link'
    # On lit le xml généré par le site
    xml = Nokogiri::XML(open(site, "UserAgent" => "Ruby-OpenURI"))
    # On le converti en html
    xml = xml.to_html
    # On le lit a nouveau
    html = Nokogiri::HTML(xml)
    # on extrait les images
    @images = html.xpath('//img')
    # on stock leurs sources dans un tableau
    @images_sources = @images.map{|node| node['src']}
end
```